# How do you deal with an "Error in setValueByCell"? --library(enmSdmX)--BRT model

Tags: geospatial

How do you deal with an "Error in setValueByCell"?

Enviromental_Rasters is a SpatRaster of climate, elevation, land cover ect.

train_Data is a dataframe with first column "presBg"- that is 1 or 0 for present   or  absent data, other columns are Enviromental data that are extracted from lats and longs from Enviromental_Rasters (SpatRaster).

```
library(enmSdmX)

brt_Adapt_West_CNC_Vars <- trainBRT(
data = train_Data,
resp = 'presBg',
preds = Adapt_West_CNC_Vars,
learningRate = 0.00001, #
treeComplexity = 2, # 
minTrees = 1200, # 
maxTrees = 10000, # 
tryBy = 'treeComplexity',
anyway = TRUE, # return models that did not converge
verbose = TRUE,
cores = 1
)
```

#### runs fine no problems

```
brtMap_Adapt_West_CNC_Vars <- predictEnmSdm(brt_Adapt_West_CNC_Vars, Enviromental_Rasters) `
```

"Error in setValueByCell(out, preds, cell = notNas, format = "raster") :
The length of "val" must be as long as or shorter than the length of "cell"."

Random forest and maxent models run in same code only BRT has issues.

Thank you for any help.